# Assigning a local @property for a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have UIView .h and .m files and in my main view controller i have this

```
PopUpRectangle *RectangeView = [[PopUpRectangle alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 538, 320, 30)]
```

this allows me to show the rectangle, but instead of doing this in each function of my view controller, I want to assign this UIView as a local @property - so its available for each function.

How is this done please ?

Comment: please spend sometime finding it on the documentation first. first read about how views & viewcontrollers work. then about declaring properties.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html

Comment: If you know `@property` then what is stopping you to write `@property (nonatomic, strong) PopUpRectangle *rectangeView;`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MyClass.h**

```
@interface MyClass : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) PopUpRectangle *rectangeView; // Public version

@end
```

**MyClass.m**

```
@interface MyClass()

// If you don't want it public remove if from the .h and add here instead

@end

@implementation MyClass

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // Alloc initWithFrame here
    // _rectangeView is the getter for rectangeView
    _rectangeView = [[PopUpRectangle alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 538, 320, 30)];
}    

- (void)someRandomMethodIMadeUp
{
    // We're calling the getter for rectangeView again but in a different way, we're calling the ivar.
    [[self rectangeView] setHidden:NO];
}

@end
```

As it has already been mentioned since you already know about `@property` why are you even asking this question. Please read up on the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html) before asking another simple and basic question that you already seem to know.